# Why doesn't Istio on the GKE create a Gateway?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, gateway

I installed Istio on the GKE from the Helm chart.
Everything went through without errors.

However, I see that the IngressGateway has not been created:

```
$> kubectl get gateway --all-namespaces
No resources found
```

How can I understand what is preventing the creation of this resource?

Answer (score 1):

With a default installation of Istio, the istio-ingressgateway is a Deployment and a Service in the istio-system namespace with an external Load Balancer.

See https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports

This can then be then used by Gateways.

Comment: I only need to bind internal gRPC traffic. Internally I am using the address `istio-ingressgateway.istio-system:50051

Comment: Well these Gateway resources are not part of an Istio installation, they are more like part of your applications (like Kubernetes Ingress resources)

Comment: I don't understand. I create gateway https://github.com/batazor/shortlink/blob/main/ops/Helm/shortlink-ingress/templates/istio-gateway.yaml and virtualService https://github.com/batazor/shortlink/blob/main/ops/Helm/shortlink-link/templates/ingress-istio.yaml#L12

Comment: Which GKE version do you have? Maybe it is this issue: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#istio-gateways

Comment: I use the original Istio 1.10 and 

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3`

Comment: output of both `kubectl get gtw -A` and `kubectl get gw -A` please